# Syntax Error when deploying django on apache2

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to host a django application on a server using apache2 and mod_wsgi.

The project itself is located at the path */usr/share/django-projects/mysite*

The virtual environment is located at the path */home/zakhar/django_test/env*

It's part of apache2 (2.4 version) conf file. In venv python version is 3.8.13

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite user=www-data group=www-data python-path=/usr/share/django-projects/mysite:/home/zakhar/django_test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages python-home=/home/zakhar/django_test/env
```

It's last error from apache arror.log

```
File "/home/zakhar/django_test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", in line 84
if (default := c.default) is None:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think apache use python 3.6.9 in global env, but not in venv

I would be very grateful if someone could help me

Comment: you can't install python 3.8.13 inside venv, python installs globally on your virtual machie, so if your appache has 3.6.9, your project also has 3.6.9 watch it in console `python3 --version`

Comment: I set python3.8.13 by default, but nothing has changed

Comment: Hello @Zakhar Yes, by default some softwares eg.(python2 or python3) is pre installed in ubuntu(linux) so to solve you issue always use virtual environment and while installing package use **python3.8** & **pip3** globally or inside env

Answer (score 1):

I installed mod_wsgi in my venv and edited */etc/apache2/mods-avaible/wsgi.load*

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/zakhar/django_test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/home/zakhar/django_test/env"
```